# layout is not defined in ejs-mate package

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXH6V.png)

[boilerplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXRs1.png)

I have no clue why layout is not defined i have install ejs-mate and ejs and still says this

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %>

<h1>All campgrounds </h1>
<div>
    <a href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campground</a>
</div>
<ul>

    <% for(let campground of campgrounds ){%>

            <li><a href = "/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>"><%=campground.title%></a></li>
    <%}%>
</ul>
```

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXadt.png)

Answer (score 2):

Probably needed to check the app.js file. I was getting this error when I omitted the ';' after: const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate').

also double check your app.engine('ejs', ejsMate)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming from your app.js file.
ensure you have the ejs-package defined and the engine specified like so:
`const engine = require('ejs-mate');` and
`app.engine('ejs', engine);`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `include` inplace of `layout` like this:-

```
  <%- include('../layouts/boilerplate'); %>
```

for more info check this link:- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application
or tell me

Answer (score 0):

try checking your app.js file whether you have written this:

```
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
```

I had the same error because I used an `app.use` instead of `app.engine`